# How to style magnific ajax pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I am trying to style a magnific pop-up that is populated with content from a uri. The content is just some text. I do not wish to use and html code as the popup is initiated from a button.

The code I have written works but the styling is horrible. How can I add styling classes the following JQuery code:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: 'www.someWebsitecontentPage.com',
        type: 'ajax',
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
        myClassOne: 'modal-content',
        callbacks: {
            // wrap the ajax request with a div that we've styled to look good
            parseAjax: function (mfpResponse) {
                mfpResponse.data = "<div class='modal-content'>" + mfpResponse.data + "</div>";
            },
            ajaxContentAdded: function () {
                return this.content;
            }
        }
    },
    closeBtnInside: true
});
```

Comment: You're asking how to style the `modal-content` div?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific: I tried to use the parseAjax function to add the div with the class, but it does not work as I expected it to. So I wanted to know how I can add classes to this popup within this function.

Comment: Do you want to modify the CSS of Magnific (the styling applied to the popup as a whole), or just the content you've loaded remotely?

Comment: Yes, the styling applied to the pop-up as a whole. The content loaded remotely cannot be modified by me.

Comment: Did you see this in the documentation? http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax_type - specifically, where it says "Popup itself should be styled in exactly the same way as an inline popup type"? You basically add a CSS class to whatever will be triggering the popup, and then add your rules to that.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easiest to build CSS selectors that started with the main wrapper class, `.mfp-content`. From there, you just add more specificity. Here's an example:

```
.mfp-content #page-content
{
    margin-top: 1em;
}

    .mfp-content #page-content h3
    {
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
```

This worked for me because I knew exactly what markup I was getting, so if your content is variable, you'd have to maybe use something like:

```
.mfp-content h3
{
    margin-top: 1em;
}

    .mfp-content p
    {
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
```

You could also build off of the div you've appended:

```
.mfp-content .modal-content
{
    margin: 1em;
}

    .mfp-content .modal-content h3
    {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
```

Comment: I already have some styling attributes for modal-content. But that class does not appear on the element. Is the html correct in the parseajax funtion?

Comment: @LiluPatel I'd try something like this instead: `mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).wrap('<div class="modal-content"></div>');` - reference the API at http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: OK.I have tried that. I checked the elements in the dev tools in chrome but that div does not seem to be getting the class appended to it. I am failing to understand why. In another pop-up where I am doing something similar except I am loading the pop-up with an onclick event on an <a> element, this works correctly. So why doesn't it work when referencing the url directly in the magnific.open() function?

Comment: I've seen before that the Chrome tools don't always show the actual markup the browser's working with; if you have Firefox+Web Developer Toolbar, there's a "Generated Html" option. That being said... I'm not sure. When I've loaded Ajax content with this plugin, I didn't modify it in any way. That worked for me, since I had control over both ends.

Comment: Yes, but the styles have not been applied so I am thinking the class is definately not being appended to the div element.